# HERE api is returning a PermissionError

Tags: here-api

I have not changed anything in the API, other than the user account password and confirmation of email. The API is constructed thus:

https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=ADDRESS&app_id=[MYAPPID]&app_code=[MYAPPCODE]

Primarily use JavaScript/REST libraries - Map Tiles and Geocoding services.

I tried restricting the account by domain, but reverted it back when I noticed this error. Has anyone reported or had this issue, and if so, how was this fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permission Errors that are thrown to reject incoming requests due to invalid credentials or missing entitlements. Please check your appid and code with any other API to see if they work properly. If not try generating another app id and code to see if that solves your problem.